# how can i add a new button button on dashboard ordres page prestashop

Tags: prestashop, orders

I am using prestashop for an ecomercial websiteand i want to export the orderss into an excel file. For that i wanted to add a new button in the dashboad orders page. 
the problem is that i really don't know how and which file i have to edit.
I was thinking about adding an html code but i tried many pages, including the adminController and it didn't work using this code:
`<button type="button">Click Me!</button>`
I know that there a module for that, but i prefer not to us it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Prestashop 1.6

You need to edit this file `/adminxxxx/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/helpers/list/list_header.tpl`

(this file extends `/adminxxxx/themes/default/template/helpers/list/list_headers.tpl`.)

have a look at the second file and find an appropriate empty block declaration where you want to put your button for example `{block name="preTable"}{/block}`.

In the first file you can override this block including your button using:

```
{block name=preTable}
    <div><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
{/block}
```

Comment: thank you very much, i've able to add a new button but not in the page i wanted. In fact i wanted to ad it in the orders list and not in one ordre details. so it was not the right file to edit :)

Comment: So it's ok? If this answers your question please mark my post as accepted. [How does accepting an answer works?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: In fact it was not OK, as i said the button was added but not in the page i wanted. I wanted it in the orders list page.

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working. `/helpers/list/list_header.tpl` is only used for list pages. So changing `/controllers/orders/helpers/list/list_headers.tpl` should only affect orders list page. It's working on my website.

Comment: it's working finely. The problem was in the section. Thanks a lot for your help :)